# Weird printf/pthread error?

Tags: c, pthreads, printf, mutex

So I'm working on a threads project and I'm testing one of my files, making sure the structs and fields are getting the correct values. I am running this function:

```
struct ReportQueue {
   sem_t count;
   pthread_mutex_t mutexAdd;
   ReportList *RQList;
};

ReportQueue *RQCreate() {
   ReportQueue *rq;

   printf("RQCreate() called\n");
   rq = calloc(1, sizeof(ReportQueue));
   sem_init(&rq->count, 0, 0);
   pthread_mutex_init(&rq->mutexAdd, NULL);
   rq->RQList = NULL;
   return rq;
}
```

With this main:

```
int main() {
   ReportQueue *rQueue;
   Report report;

   rQueue = RQCreate();
   printf("SemCount: |%d| RQList: |%d| MutexAdd |%d|\n", rQueue->count, rQueue->RQList, rQueue->mutexAdd);
   printf("SemCount: |%d|\n", rQueue->count);
   printf("RQList: |%d|\n", rQueue->RQList);
   printf("MutexAdd: |%d|\n", rQueue->mutexAdd);

   return;
}
```

And I am getting this output:

```
RQCreate() called
SemCount: |0| RQList: |128| MutexAdd |0|
SemCount: |0|
RQList: |0|
MutexAdd: |0|
```

Which doesn't make any sense to me. The value of "RQList" should not change depending on how I print it out? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you people mind helping me out please instead of voting down my question for reasons I don't know why? I think this is a valid question to be asked. To my knowledge, the value shouldn't change.

Comment: what is RQList and why is it %d? Is it a decimal/int/numeric variable at all?

Comment: Use %p to print pointer values.

Comment: Well given my calloc call which initializes everything to 0 or NULL, I thought it would be ok to use %d as a valid format specifier to test the values. RQList is supposed to be a linked list of ReportLists.

Comment: %d or %p should matter here AFAICS.. this is weird to me :D

Comment: Thank you hmjd. But I still get different values for the RQList. I get 0x80 for the long print and (nil) for the single printf.

Comment: you do not print out pointers with %d as it's said before you will have to create a function which will loop through your list and print out needed values and/or get the size of it with sizeof(&RQList) and then %d it. and so on and so forth AFAIK.

Comment: @SergeyBenner I see what you're saying. So given that, does that mean I can ignore the different values that are being printed out now?

Comment: I am unsure of the underlying types of sem_t and pthread_mutex_t. IIRC, a mismatch between argument type and format specifier is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I tried it and for me it prints 0 and 0 alright. p or d (for 0 d is fine!)

Comment: printing the Mutex as an int though.. thats not correct and llvm doesn't even let me do that stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a minimal example that works fine... this isn't an answer but shows that all seems ok

#### + it didn't fit in a comment :D

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct ReportQueue {
   sem_t count;
   pthread_mutex_t mutexAdd;
   int *RQList;
};

struct ReportQueue *RQCreate() {
   struct ReportQueue *rq;

   printf("RQCreate() called\n");
   rq = calloc(1, sizeof(struct ReportQueue));
   sem_init(&rq->count, 0, 0);
   pthread_mutex_init(&rq->mutexAdd, NULL);
   rq->RQList = NULL;
   return rq;
}

int main() {
   struct ReportQueue *rQueue;

   rQueue = RQCreate();
   printf("SemCount: |%d| RQList: |%d| \n", rQueue->count, (int)rQueue->RQList);
   printf("SemCount: |%d|\n", rQueue->count);
   printf("RQList: |%d|\n", (int)rQueue->RQList);

   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `%d` to print out variables of type `sem_t`, `pthread_mutex_t`, or pointers.  At best you'll get implementation defined behavior (if `sem_t` and `pthread_mutex_t` happen to be typedefs for `int` and pointers happen to be the same size as an int).  But in general, you'll get undefined behavior since those types may have nothing to do with `int` - which is what `%d` tells `printf()` the corresponding argument's type is.

That's why the `printf()` calls produce output that doesn't make any sense.  You're passing arguments to `printf()` that don't make any sense.